# Return dictionary name based on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to python and I want to do a reverse lookup of a dictionary. I have a dictionary built from a JSON file that looks similar to this:

```
{
    "dict1" : {
        "data1" : "a",
        "data2" : "b",
        "data3" : "c",
        "data4" : "d",
        "data5" : "e"
    },
    "dict2" : {
        "data1" : "f",
        "data2" : "g",
        "data3" : "h",
        "data4" : "i",
        "data5" : "j"
    }

}
```

If  I want to know which dictionary, 'dict1' or 'dict2', contains the value j, assuming all the values are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a dictionary of dictionaries is really not a problem, assuming your data structure is well established and you know at what depth you will find things.  If the structure goes much deeper than you have, however, things get complicated.  A simple solution for your question is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

json_dict = {
    "dict1": {
        "data1": "a",
        "data2": "b",
        "data3": "c",
        "data4": "d",
        "data5": "e"
    },
    "dict2": {
        "data1": "f",
        "data2": "g",
        "data3": "h",
        "data4": "i",
        "data5": "j"
    },
    "dict3": {
        "data42": "c",
        "data43": "g"
    }
}


def which_dict_key(value, dicts):
    '''
    Return a list of keys for a dictionary where the
    value dictionary for that key includes the value
    provided.
    '''

    return [key for key in dicts if value in dicts[key].values()]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(which_dict_key("j", json_dict))
    print(which_dict_key("c", json_dict))
    print(which_dict_key("q", json_dict))
    print(which_dict_key("g", json_dict))
```

Which produces:

```
['dict2']
['dict1', 'dict3']
[]
['dict3', 'dict2']
```

Comment: This is working for me. I was beginning to think it was impossible, because I think dictionaries were not meant to be used in this way. Thank you for the post.

Answer (score 2):

Unless my JSON knowledge fails me, it looks like you've actually got a dict within a dict there? One easy way to solve this issue would be to extract these dict objects out into seperate variables, let's say you extract these into "d1" and "d2".

We can see if a dictionary in python contains a specific value with the following line of code:

```
"j" in d1.values()
```

This will return true if "j" is the value of any key within the dictionary. If you do this on the top level dictionary in your example it won't work, you will need to write extra code to recursively search in dictionaries assigned to a key within the top level dictionary.

So it will be easier to extract your dictionaries out into seperate variables, and then call the above line of code in an if statement to determine if the value is within the dictionary. You'll need to track each dictionary somehow, loop through these dictionaries and store whether or not each dictionary contains your value.

Comment: Yikes. This seems way more complicated that I initially thought. The JSON file is something that I create using fileIO. But you are correct it's a dictionary of dictionaries. I'll work through what you posted and let you know.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other issues